# Excel Vlookup across 2 workbooks

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I have two columns of data in different excel workbooks:

I want to compare all the data in column C of Workbook 2 against the data in Column D of Workbook 1.

If the data in column C matches the data in Column D I would like it to be pulled out into a different work book in Columns A and B.  But I have over 37,000 cells of data in the columns

Is there anyway to do this across workbooks with this much data? I think I can use a VLookup but I am not having much success.

Thanks!

Comment: If you've tried VLOOKUP, [edit] your question to include how you are attempting it, along with the formula, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match data if its the same, I think an `IF` function would be much better than `VLOOKUP` in this case.

For example, say I have workbook1, workbook2, and workbook3. And now I want to compare column C in workbook2 to column D in workbook1. If the cell in both these columns is the same, I want to return it to workbook3, in column A.

In simple

```
=IF(Cell in Column D of workbook1 = Cell in Column C of workbook2, Return Cell in Column C of workbook2, otherwise return "")
```

(where `["" is nothing]`), the formula would be as follows:

```
=IF(Sheet1!D1=Sheet2!C1,Sheet2!C1,"")
```

It's easy to implement if you type it in the cell, then navigate to the workbooks and cells you want to check. Once you have this, you can drag it down.